# How to use a named_association for has_many_through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to write this:

```
has_many :sales, foreign_key: :buyer_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purchased_books, class_name: 'Book', through: :sales, source: :book
```

as this:

```
has_many :purchases, class_name: 'Sale', foreign_key: :buyer_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purchased_books, class_name: 'Book', through: :sales, source: :book
```

It gives me the following error at the moment:

```
Could not find the association :sales in model User (ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError)
```

And writing it has_many :sales is grammatically incorrect when foreign_key: :buyer_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :through key must reference an association that is defined.

```
has_many :purchases, class_name: 'Sale', foreign_key: :buyer_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :purchased_books, class_name: 'Book', through: :purchases, source: :book
```